# How to setup a VSTS build definition to publish Azure Functions with this configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

We are using VS 2017 on a single solution with multiple projects and we right mouse click and deploy 3 C# Azure Function to two different Azure Function apps with slots.

How do you set up the VSTS build definition to accomplish this on every check in?

We are using the DLLs and setting up the function.json this way. I don’t know if we need to deploy differently based on this type of configuration.

```
"scriptFile": "..\\bin\\target.dll",
"entryPoint": "target.Application.Run"
```

Comment: This [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/06/01/deploying-visual-studio-2017-function-projects-with-vsts/) might be useful if you haven't seen it already. We followed this process after some discussions on the Azure functions github

Answer (score 3):

I was able to create a VSTS deployment through the following steps

**Solutions structure**

[image]

**Build Configuration Steps**

1. Sync from master branch
2. Added Nuget Restore using default options
3. Added MSBuild Step with the followign optons

   - Project : vstsSolution.sln (Selected using '...')
   - MSBuild Version: Latest
   - MSBuild Architechture: MSBuild x86
   - Clean: Checked
   - Create Log File: Checked
4. Added App Service Deploy for Function App1

   - Azure Subscription: Target Subscription
   - App Service Name: Target Function App
   - Deploy to slot: If you check this it allows you to select the actual slot you want to deploy to
   - Package or folder: FunctionApp1\bin\Debug\net461
5. Added App Service Deploy for Function App1

   - Package or folder: FunctionApp2\bin\Debug\net461
6. Make sure you selected "Hosted VS2017" Agent Queue for this build.

   **All Build Steps**

   [image]
7. Triggers: Enable Continuous Integration. So that both function app deploy every time you check-in.

   **Continuous Integration**

   [image]